# How to create dynamic url in Spring Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

```
@GetMapping("/deposit")
public String deposit(@RequestParam("amount") double amount,@RequestParam ("id") int id) {

    if (amount > 0) {
        accountService.deposit(id, amount);
    }
    return "redirect:/account";
}
```

I have two parameters that I need to send from my html file, my problem is that 'amount' parameter should be coming from html file. How can I dynamically do that?

```
 <input type="number" id="amount">
 <a th:href="@{/account/deposit(id=${account.id}, amount=????)}">Deposit</a>
```

I want to put the input value into amount in th:href would appreciate any help.

Comment: A [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) is typically used to submit user-entered data to the server. You cannot use Thymeleaf for this, directly. Thymeleaf runs on the server. The server does not know what value(s) the user is going to enter, when Thymeleaf renders your template into HTML. (Thymeleaf does not exist in the rendered output sent to the browser.)

Comment: Just pass the `amount` that the endpoint receives to the thymeleaf template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is mentioned by @andrewJames it would be mush easier to submit this value using form. For example:

**In your HTML**

```
<form th:action="@{/account/deposit(id=${account.id})}" method="post">
    <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount">
    <button type="submit">Deposit</button>
</form>
```

**In your Controller**

```
@PostMapping( "/deposit" )
public String onDepositSubmit( @RequestParam Long id, @RequestParam Integer amount ) {
    if (amount > 0) {
        accountService.deposit(id, amount);
    }
    return "redirect:/account";
}
```

This would be the easiest solution. However, it is possible to dinamically alter a link as at the client-side the link is already rendered to a normal link (e.g. `/account/deposit?id=12345`), so you can manipulate it using JS as you wish, for example something like this (using `JQuery`):

```
<input type="number" id="amount">
<a th:href="@{/account/deposit(id=${account.id},amount=0)}" id="amount_link">Deposit</a>

<script>
    let amountInput = $( '#amount' )
    let amountLink = $( '#amount_link' )
    amountInput.keyup( function() {
        let url = new URL( amountLink.attr( 'href' ) );
        url.searchParams.set( 'amount', amountInput.val() )
        amountLink.attr( 'href', url.toString() )
    } )
</script>
```

Which would create a `keyup` event listener on input and update link every time the character is typed or deleted. However, this is needlessly complicated and as such is considered a bad practice.